# 1ms precise timer implementation using win32 api

Tags: c, windows, qt, timer

I have 3 threads running in my application and I want to call 3 periodic functions respectively from the 3 threads. I tried using the setTimer api but due to improper implementation the timer is not getting triggered.
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: The one who can help you is the supplier of the faulty driver. Anybody else would need much more info. Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.